# How to send notification with functions firebase/firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a little problem. I want to send notifications when someone add comment to posts in my app. I dont use database only firestore. I have something like this for now.

```
 export const sendNotification = functions.firestore
 .document('Comments/{commentId}')
 .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const senderUid = snap.get('idUser');
        const receiverUid = snap.get('idUserImage');
        const comment = snap.get('comment');

 });
```

Now how to send ntification to receiverUid with text - comment?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging).

Take a look on this example: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart